# Change decimal seperator of GXT Numberfield to comma

Tags: forms, gwt, decimal, number-formatting, gxt

Is it possible to change the decimal seperator of GXT Numberfield from point to comma? I searched and tried a lot, but can't find a solution.

When filling the form field of type "FloatField" with a number like 67,8 - the value of the field is switched to 67.8. So the field accecpts inputs with commas, but the NumberFormat to display it, is simply wrong.
How can i change that?

Thanks in advance, David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, nobody had an answer, but a colleague of me have had the same problem and solved it. So, if anyone in future will search for it, here is the answer:

You can make your own FloatField class and override the behavior. The class (in the simpliest form) would be like this:

```
 package org.example.myforms

 public class FloatField extends NumberField<Float> {

       /**
       * Constructor
       */
       public FloatField() {
             super(new NumberPropertyEditor.FloatPropertyEditor());
             init();
       }

       private void init () {
             // disply float values with comma as decimal seperator
             String pattern = "0.0;";
             super.setFormat(NumberFormat.getFormat(pattern));
       }
}
```

To use this field e.g. in your *.ui.xml you have to import your `myform` package:

```
<ui:UiBinder 
    ...
    xmlns:myform="urn:import:org.example.myforms"
    >
```

Then you can use it:

```
<myform:FloatField ui:field="field_1" allowDecimals="true"/>
```